# SSD thinks it's going bad

Tags: windows, laptop, ssd

So I purchased this ADATA SP580 a few months ago for my laptop. Had no issues until recently, the laptop started freezing out of nowhere. I went ahead and did a clean install of Windows to see if the problem persisted. So far, the laptop is running fine, but I have decided to check the health of the SSD, and what I just saw was nuts.
[image]

The Lifetime writes absolutely do not reflect the reality, because I use this laptop occasionally (light web browsing), I do most of my work on my main desktop. Also the number of bad sectors seems strange for a relatively new SSD.

Here comes the weird part: I pressed the "Repeat Test" button after two minutes, and the Lifetime writes went up a few hundred terabytes ! (of course I wasn't doing anything on it ). 
[image]
If I'll do this in another few minutes, the result will be the same.

Things that I have tried:

- full surface scan revealed no bad sectors

At this point, I am clueless what is going on with this SSD.

What can cause this problem ?

Comment: The cause is most likely bad hardware. If the disk is still under warranty, then ask for a replacement.

Comment: I would go ahead and try the warranty replacement. When you send it in, they should do a SMART test on it and check a few other things. I would also be sure to explain the absurd lifetime writes. I had a similar issue a few months ago with a Samsung drive. After I sent it off for warranty I had reinstalled with a different disk and had the same problem. I then knew I had a bad SATA controller. Samsung checked the SSD, it had no errors and passed the SMART test perfectly. By time I got the SSD back I had a new motherboard, reinstalled everything and it was all good.

Comment: Download the diagnostic/support tools from the manufacturer for this drive. If the results are as you say, clearly the sentinel pro software is not working properly.

Comment: This is the kind of thing having 2 SSDs & 2 SATA cables would be handy for; eliminate the most obvious causes first. I just spent a week fighting a machine which turned out to simply have one bad SATA cable.